# Assign output of a shell command to a variable

Tags: linux, shell

I want to assign the output of a shell command *to* a variable.

If I directly echo the command, the code will execute correctly:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#result[@]}; i++)); do
    echo ${result[$i]} | awk '{print $1}'
    done
```

But, if I assign it to a variable,

```
size=`${result[$i]} | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $size
```

Or

```
size=$(${result[$i]} | awk '{print $1}')
echo $size
```

They are not working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: While this is more or less a typo error, the canonical is *[How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437)*. Despite the unspecific title, it covers the case of ***(variable) input to the external command*** (in a (Bash) variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the `echo`

```
size=$(echo ${result[$i]} | awk '{print $1}')
```

---

Here the output the the `echo` is passed as input to the `awk`

The `$()` or back ticks just run the command and assign it to a variable, so when you just write

```
${result[$i]} | awk '{print $1}'
```

it won't give you anything as nothing is passed as input to the `awk` command.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I am stuck here for 4 hours...
Thank you for such a detailed presentation of solution.

Comment: I would like to thanks you again for your presentation